# Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::setTrustedProxies

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have just cloned Laravel 8 /Vue js project and I am trying to run it,
I have got this error

```
Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::setTrustedProxies() must be of the type int, array given, called in C:\lab\vue-laravel-crud-2\vue-laravel-crud\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php on line 54
```

I have googled this error and I have added this to my code but It was not working
This is how was the code

```
protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
```

I have replaced it with this code

```
protected $headers = [
        Request::HEADER_FORWARDED => 'FORWARDED',
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST => 'X_FORWARDED_HOST',
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT => 'X_FORWARDED_PORT',
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO => 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO',
    ];
```

But the error is remaining , do anyone has an idea about this error as I have googled it a lot and nothing was found .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: what if you try replacing your TrustProxies.php file contents with the contents from the laravel generated code for the file. You could try getting the file contents from https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php